# How to do toolbar transparent used as action bar like below screenshot?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

[image]

```
     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentDrawer.FragmentDrawerListener {

private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private FragmentDrawer drawerFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0);
}
```

Toolbar

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
local:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
local:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

I want to put image like cureent play app.
I am using this link example to achieve this 
 http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Please help
thanks in advance.

Comment: dude it's 12 am..go to sleep

Comment: please help if you found any solution..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a reference of this link 
http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2015/04/11/android-and-the-transparent-status-bar.aspx

This is easy to achieve by using the following XML attributes in your Styles.xml and Styles(v21).xml:

```
 <!-- Make the status bar traslucent -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```